# Can I create an AKS cluster without starting it? (Stopped state)

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I'm using AKS and my goal is to create an AKS cluster in the stopped state. The reason for this is that I want to create the cluster, but I don't want to incur any cost until a future point. This is because in this usecase, the costs of cluster are tied to the computation it's performing, and our regular usage is to start the cluster on demand when we have a job to run.

Currently, I have tried creating a cluster in 2 ways:

1. Using the Azure console: https://portal.azure.com/?quickstart=True#create/microsoft.aks
2. Using the Azure CLI: `az aks create`

In both approaches, Azure first deploys the cluster, and then in a second step, I need to `STOP` the cluster.

Is it possible to create the cluster without starting it?

Perhaps the answer is that a new cluster needs to be created for every job, but I'll need to dig into this to understand any timing/cost tradeoffs doing this.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think so, since the [create/update operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) doesn't have a parameter for it, but I'll ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to create a cluster in stopped state. You should test the time difference between Create and Start. You'll probably find that there's little difference between the two operations and to just create a new cluster for each job... Create might even be faster :)